# Getting every combination of Queens?

Tags: java, backtracking, n-queens

```
public class SomeQueens {

static Stack<Integer> s= new Stack<Integer>();
static int Solved = 0;
static int current = 0;   


 public static int solve(int n) { // n is 8

   while(current < n) { // should I use current < n instead

     for (int i = current; i < n; i++) {
       if(validPosition(i)) {
            s.push(i);
            current = 0; 
      }
   }

   if(!validPosition(current)) {  
      if(s.empty()) {
           break;
      }
       if(!s.empty()) {
          s.pop();
          current++; 
}
}

 if(s.size() == n) {
      s.pop();
      current++; 
      printSolution(s);// this is a method, but it shouldn't matter for this
      Solved++;
  }
  }
    return Solved;
  }
 public static boolean validPosition(int column)  {
  for( int row = 0; row < s.size(); row++)
      if(s.get(row) == column || ((column - s.get(row)) == (s.size() - row)) || 
      ((s.get(row) - column) == (s.size() - row)) ) 
        return false; // there's a conflict
    return true; // no conflict;     
}

//it's called by int num = solve(n); 
//sop("There're" + num + "sols to the" + n "queens prob");
```

This is a subsection of my program for NQueens, but I seem to always get: There are 0 solutions to the 8-queens problem. I  tried debugging with system.out.prints in the main method, which led me to guess that there would be something wrong in my boolean method, but I don't think it's doing anything wrong.
I'm unsure if my while statement is incorrect or if the break inside the while loop is initialized before anything is even done. Thanks for the help and guidance and I'm sorry if my program and explanation makes no sense

Comment: why don't use recursive?

Comment: There seems to be no return statement for `int solve(int n)`. This should not compile.

Comment: I cannot use recursive and I apologize for not placing that -- now i did. Sorry for not clarifying things.

Answer (score 1):

Here is why you instantly get a zero:

```
s.push(0);
while(s.size() > n) // n is 8
{
 //...
}
return Solved;
```

When the program arrives at the while-condition `s` has a size of one and `n` is 8. This will instantly fail and cause the method to return a zero.

But that's not the only problem with the algorithm. You should seriously rethink it.

Comment: i took your criticism and rewrote it